# $1_{\limsup A_n} = \limsup 1_{A_n} $

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Do you have some hints on how to prove the following relation? I think it should be quite straightforward, but I cannot see it.
$$
1_{\limsup A_n} = \limsup 1_{A_n} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each side is a way of writing the function
$$ x\mapsto\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x\in A_n\text{ for infinitely many }n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

This should be easy to prove by unfolding the definitions of $1_A$ and $\limsup$ (for sequences for sets and numbers, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1_{\cap_n B_n} = \inf_n 1_{B_n}$, and $1_{\cup_n C_n} = \sup_n 1_{C_n}$.

Then note that $\operatorname{Limsup}_n A_n = \cap_n \cup_{k \ge n} A_k$, and apply the above (using monotonicity and inclusion as appropriate).